# Fix connecting betwen 2 virtual machine in Ubuntu 18

Tags: virtualbox-networking

I have 2 VirtualBox machines that have full connection, but when I `ping 10.0.2.7` which is another machine's `enp0s3` address, it show `Request time out`. Please help me. I am using Ubuntu 18.x.x. Thanks a lot.

Comment: check out Table 6.1. Overview of Networking Modes https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what “full connection” means… As [@AlexOnLinux noted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169275/fix-connecting-betwen-2-virtual-machine-in-ubuntu-18#comment1950990_1169275), VirtualBox offers several [networking modes](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes) and you must choose the appropriate one.

If your guests don’t need to access the internet, you can use **Host-only** to connect them both together (and with the host as well).

If you are allowed to connect more than one client to the network, you can use **Bridged** mode to allow guests to access each other, the host and the internet as well.

**NAT Network** might also be interesting for you (but I have no experiences with it).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to connect again and really thanks a lot.

Comment: @TruongNangToan Were you satisfied with my answer? If I could solve your problem, it would be nice if you [accepted](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer (✓). In the opposite case, please clarify your needs using [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1169275/edit) or comments. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers), [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/217657)